# How to use port 443 for both IIS and Tomcat on same server for two different applications

Tags: .net, tomcat, iis, hosting

We are having an application server , we need to host .Net Web api with secure HTTPS link on port 443 using IIS , also a front application (using JAVA) in Tomcat with secured HTTPS link on same 443 port.

We deployed Java front end in tomcat with 443 port but now when tried to start a site in IIS on same port 443 it is not starting since port already in use.

So what steps can be taken so that we will have two different application hosted in IIS and Tomcat with using same 443 port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure a reverse proxy for IIS, use port 443 as the traffic forwarding port, and set the two different applications to other ports. Because IIS is used as a reverse proxy server, you can use port 443 to forward to by creating a rewrite rule. on two other different application ports.

you can look at this: [Proxy IIS Server to Tomcat Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59085932/proxy-iis-server-to-tomcat-application)

Comment: After following these steps, I was able to run both apps on 443. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Deploy a reverse proxy server(Nginx, Apache or else) with port 443 , IIS and Tomcat use other port. Config the proxy server to proxy the traffic of IIS and Tomcat.

Comment: By using reverse proxy server, will user be able to open two different sites (with no commonality in URL) like "https://example.com/login" and "https://dummy.com/login" ?

Comment: If you don't know yet, IIS itself can be that reverse proxy.

Answer (score 2):

First, let IIS be the web server that takes all traffic.

Second, configure all your sites on IIS at port 443. SNI support in IIS 8+ allows you to host multiple HTTPS sites on the same machine,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-server-name-indication-sni-ssl-scalability

Third, if one of the sites is Java/Tomcat based, use HttpPlatformHandler to forward its traffic to Tomcat (let IIS control which port Tomcat should use),

https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/the-rough-history-of-iis-httpplatformhandler/#the-magical-httpplatformhandler